# Как вызвать Fragment из Activity через кнопку?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Не могу вызвать Фрагмент из Активити. У меня есть главная активность и есть Фрагмент. И мне путем нажатия кнопки на главной активности нужно вызвать страницу фрагмента. Я новичок в андроид программировании.Подскажите кто знает.

Конструкция:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, someFragment.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Для фрагментов не работает.

Подскажите как можно вызвать Фрагмент из главной Активити путем нажатия кнопки?

Answer (score 3):

Собственно что вам нужно сделать?

Создайте в вашей Activity такой XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

А эту функцию поместите в clickListener вашей кнопки:

```
void onButtonClick() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new MyFragment()); // or replace с теми же параметрами
        .addToBackStack(null) // если необходимо, чтоб по нажатию "назад" вы могли вернуться на предыдущий фрагмент. Вместо null можно задать свой ключ.
        .commit();
}
```

- `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(str);`

  Добавьте эту транзакцию в задний стек. Это означает, что транзакция будет запомнена после ее фиксации и изменит ее действие, когда позже выскочит из стека.
- `fragmentTransaction.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)`

  Замените существующий фрагмент, добавленный в контейнер. Это по сути то же самое, что и вызов remove (Fragment) для всех добавленных в настоящее время фрагментов, которые были добавлены с помощью одного и того же контейнера, а затем добавьте (int, Fragment, String) те же аргументы, которые приведены здесь.
- `fragmentTransaction.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag`)

  Добавить фрагмент в состояние активности. Этот фрагмент может также иметь свой вид (если Fragment.onCreateView возвращает ненулевой) в представление контейнера активности.

Вот [тут](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/175-urok-105-android-3-fragments-dinamicheskaja-rabota.html) неплохой урок по фрагментам.

Comment: Я создал главную страницу Activity, с кнопкой которая должна открыть список RecyclerView которая находится во фрагменте. Так вот я не могу посмотреть работоспособность приложения, так как не запускается фрагмент со списком RecyclerView когда нажимаю на кнопку.

Comment: Ну по "не запускается фрагмент" сложно понять вашу проблему! Тот код который я привел, он стандартен. Если у вас есть другая проблема, то создайте второй вопрос и приложите туда лог ошибки и код вызова фрагмента.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Где-то внутри вашего Активити, в функции-реакции на нажатие кнопки:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new MyFragment()); // или .replace(R.id....)
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Здесь `R.id.fragment_container` - это контейнер для фрагмента внутри лейаута активити

Comment: В коде ошибку не выдает, но при нажатии кнопки приложении аварийно завершается.

Comment: @ANTARES и какая ошибка?

Comment: 2020-07-31 13:06:57.565 3920-3920/com.antares.peretz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.antares.peretz, PID: 3920
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080125 (com.antares.peretz:id/salad_recycler) for fragment SaladFragment{e6358e6 (1a6bd63b-7223-46e9-925b-2f725bb522ea) id=0x7f080125}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:875).   Полный текст не помешается сюда

Comment: @ANTARES эта ошибка не относится к вопросу. Скорее всего этот самый ваш id не является частью родительского Активити в котором вы пытаетесь исполнить ваш код - R.id.fragment_container - должен быть частью родительского лейаута, вот в него вы и помещаете свой фрагмент

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Буду дальше разбираться!

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, что требуется. Используйте navigation

Добавьте страницу в навигации, протяните ей линию. После зайдите в активити и в public View onCreateView допишите прослушиватель кнопкии и само действие навигации. Не забудьте использовать свой id кнопки и R.id

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    ImageButton game = view.findViewById(R.id.game);
    game.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_navigation_home_to_fragment_igri);
        }

    });
```